# How do I use FinancialData to obtain company revenue and income?

Tags: curated-data, finance, wolfram-alpha-queries

I'd like to make a plot of a company's revenue and income over time.  I can do this via Wolfram Alpha pretty easily, just by searching ["Ford revenue and earnings from 2000 to 2012"](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Ford%20revenue%20and%20earnings%20from%202000%20to%202012).  As such I can, if necessary, tease out the data from a corresponding `WolframAlpha` call.

Rather than resorting to Wolfram Alpha, I assumed `FinancialData` would be more appropriate.  Surprisingly, from an initial inspection of the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FinancialData.html), it does not seems like there is an easy way to get these two particular properties.

My question is - can I reliably calculate revenue and/or net income (i.e. profit) from the supported properties of `FinancialData`?  Perhaps based off of `EarningsPerShare`?

Answer (score 4):

Well, I'm not sure if you could get **historical** financial highlights from any place rather than SEC itself...

If you want to find historical annual reports per company, please use the following link (remember to substitute "microsoft" with your desired company name):

http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/srch-edgar?text=microsoft+10-K&first=2003&last=2013

But if you want to download the **last** available key statistics, there are many webpages where you can download it. For instance, try to import key statistics directly from Yahoo! Finance using:

`Import["http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=MSFT+Key+Statistics","Data"][[2, 1]][[1, 7]]//TableForm`

## EDITED

I've done a little research. Please try to use this code:

`FordRev=WolframAlpha[#,{{"IQuarterlyValuesTable:Revenue:FinancialData", 1},"ComputableData"}][[5,2]]&/@(StringJoin["ford revenue ",ToString[#]]&/@(2002+Range[10]))`

Now see the revenue plot:

`ListLinePlot[FordRev]`

[image]

You can also use:

`BarChart[FordRev, ChartLabels -> {2002 + Range[10]}]`

[image]

For the historical net income use:

`FordNet = 
 WolframAlpha[#, {{"IQuarterlyValuesTable:NetIncome:FinancialData",1},"ComputableData"}][[5,2]] & /@(StringJoin["ford net income ",ToString[#]]&/@(2002+Range[10]))`

Now you can see the barchart:

`BarChart[FordNet, ChartLabels -> {2002 + Range[10]}]`

[image]

## EDITED

You can also "generalize" the code. Try to use:

`Rev[x_]:=WolframAlpha[#,{{"IQuarterlyValuesTable:Revenue:FinancialData",1},"ComputableData"}][[5,2]]&/@(StringJoin[ToString[x], " revenue ",ToString[#]]&/@(2002+Range[10]))`

Now you compare multiple companies:

`ListLinePlot[{Rev[microsoft],Rev[oracle],Rev[GE]}]`

The chart:

[image]

Comment: P.S.: I'm still trying to include the net income historical data...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, +1.  Like I said in the Q, I already know how to do this through `WolframAlpha`, I am trying to find a solution using `FinancialData`.

Comment: As far as I know, it's not available such information through FinancialData...

Answer (score 2):

You can get an appropriate series id from [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompanyData.html) and use the following function.

```
plotCompanyFundamentalDataOneSeries[symbol_, startDate_, endDate_,id_] := 
  Module[{mycompany, mycompanydata},
  mycompany = EntityValue[Interpreter["Company"][symbol], "Company"];
  mycompanydata =EntityValue[mycompany, 
    Dated[id, Interval[{DateObject[startDate], DateObject[endDate]}]]];
  DateListPlot[mycompanydata, PlotLabel -> symbol <> ":" <> id, 
   PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]]
```

Example:

```
GraphicsColumn[{plotCompanyFundamentalDataOneSeries["FORD", {2001, 1, 1}, {2015, 1, 1},
 "TotalRevenue"],plotCompanyFundamentalDataOneSeries["AAPL",
 {2001, 1, 1}, {2015, 1, 1}, "TotalRevenue"]}]
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason, `Dated` with `Interval` does not produce results for me. See: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/201022/54350