# How to get time series data from Entity["Company",...]?

Tags: curated-data, finance, entity

In my notebook, I have a cell that displays AT&T's revenue for one particular year (the year 2010):

```
EntityValue[Entity["Company", "ATandT::93zf2"], 
            Dated["TotalRevenue", 2010]]
```

The above works perfectly. The revenue for 2010 is displayed. However, I now wish to obtain time series data of the revenue. In other words, I wish to get the revenue for the years 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015. For that, I tried the below (based on [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/200021)):

```
EntityValue[Entity["Company", "ATandT::93zf2"], 
            Dated["TotalRevenue", 
                  Interval[{DateObject[{2010}],
                            DateObject[{2015}]}]]]
```

This time, Mathematica returns no useful values; it returns the expression unchanged. Where did I go wrong? How can I get time series data of company revenue?

Mathematica version: 11.2.0.0

Comment: This call works for me in 12.0 but not 11.3. Does putting [`CloudEvaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudEvaluate.html) around this call give you an answer? This will evaluate your call in the most recent kernel version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the comments, your syntax works as expected in M12. For earlier versions you can use:

```
EntityValue[
    Entity["Company", "ATandT::93zf2"],
    EntityProperty[
        "Company",
        "TotalRevenue",
        {"Date" -> Interval[{DateObject[{2010}],DateObject[{2015}]}]}
    ]
]
```

[image]